# Generate Narrative Report from Summary Score Table

Tags: excel, vba

I'm looking to do something a little more advanced using Excel. I would essentially like to create a comprehensive narrative report from values that would be entered in a separate table.

There are sections of the report I'm looking to create that would always be the same. However, what I would like to change in that narrative are: student scores, student name, and student gender.

I've provided a link to a sample excel file of what I am looking to accomplish (the actual report would be closer to 9-10 pages). In short, I have one table (Table 1), which would include a summary of scores for a test for a particular student. I'm looking to create a button that would generate a narrative based on those values, as well as fill in the name of the student whose pronoun would change based on their gender (both the "student name" and "gender" fields are found and would be edited as needed under Table 1).

For instance, if I enter the student name as "Mike" and gender as "Male" and click a "generate report" button, it would fill in those values throughout the report.

I'm assuming this would be done through VBA, but not sure exactly where/how to kick off this process.

Here is what I have so far:

```
Sub Add2Formula()
' Add text

For Each c In Selection
c.Activate
ActiveCell.FormulaR1C1 = "report text here" & ActiveCell.Formula
Next c

End Sub
```

What I'm having trouble with is making the table and narrative report talk to each other (so that the repot would dynamically change based on updated values for another student).

I'm running Windows 10 and Microsoft Office Pro Plus (2019).

Any pieces of advice/suggestions are greatly appreciated.

[Sample Workbook] http://www.mediafire.com/file/aq1s5n9ngyeb64v/file

Darko

Comment: Honestly this sounds like using MSWord's mail merge would be a better solution.  Use Excel as your data source and let Word do all the heavy lifting.

Comment: Thanks Frank! That's a fantastic idea. I have a basic handle on the process, but if for example, I have multiple scores for one student that need to be plugged in throughout the report? (as I would have multiple entries for one variable). Is there a way I could specify the row that Word reads from in Excel (as opposed to grabbing only the first record in the specified column?)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try,

```
Sub test()
    Dim shpRpt As Shape
    Dim Ws As Worksheet
    Dim myString As String
    Dim sName As String, sTest1 As String, sTest2 As String
    Dim sTest3 As String, sTest4 As String
    Dim sGender As String
    
    
    Set Ws = ActiveSheet
    Set shpRpt = Ws.Shapes("Report")
    
    With Ws
        sName = .Range("a12")
        sTest1 = .Range("b4")
        sTest2 = .Range("c4")
        sTest3 = .Range("b5")
        sTest4 = .Range("c5")
        If .Range("c12") = "male" Then
            sGender = "His"
        Else
            sGender = "Her"
        End If
    End With
  
 
    myString = "The Math was administered for " & sName & "'s assessment. The Math is a standardized measure of development for Sample High School," _
        & "and places a strong emphasis on child-friendly, developmentally appropriate features and tasks. The WISC-V is an individually" _
        & "administered assessment that reports scores as Raw Scores (RS) with a mean (average) of 100 and standard deviation of 15," _
        & "with most people scoring between 85 and 115. Tests administered in the school environment do not capture every aspect of math ability;" _
        & " however, these tests are useful in predicting how intense instruction needs to be in order for the individual to master academic content. " _
        & sName & "'s Overall Math Test performance on the school-based measure of cognitive processing abilities falls within the Average range (RS=" & sTest1 & ";PR=" & sTest2 & "). " _
        & vbCrLf & vbCrLf _
        & "Algebra is a branch of mathematics dealing with symbols and the rules for manipulating those symbols. On this subtest," _
        & "Mike scored within the Significantly Below Average range (RS=" & sTest3 & ";PR=" & sTest4 & "). " & sGender & " scores varied quite drastically throughout the assessment."
   
   
   shpRpt.TextFrame2.TextRange = myString
End Sub
```

Comment: this worked extremely well too! Seems like I have a great starting point with these ideas.